# Spark Scala input empty values according result from self joined dataframe query

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I struggle to write my spark scala code to fill rows for which the coverage is empty using self join with conditions.

This is the data :

```
+----+--------------+----------+--------+
| ID | date_in_days | coverage | values |
+----+--------------+----------+--------+
|  1 | 2020-09-01   |          | 0.128  |
|  1 | 2020-09-03   |        0 | 0.358  |
|  1 | 2020-09-04   |        0 | 0.035  |
|  1 | 2020-09-05   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-06   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-19   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-12   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-18   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-11   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-16   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-21   |       13 | 0.554  |
|  1 | 2020-09-23   |          |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-30   |          |        |
+----+--------------+----------+--------+
```

Expected result :

```
+----+--------------+----------+--------+
| ID | date_in_day  | coverage | values |
+----+--------------+----------+--------+
|  1 | 2020-09-01   |       -1 | 0.128  |
|  1 | 2020-09-03   |        0 | 0.358  |
|  1 | 2020-09-04   |        0 | 0.035  |
|  1 | 2020-09-05   |        0 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-06   |        0 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-19   |        0 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-12   |        0 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-18   |        0 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-11   |        0 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-16   |        0 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-21   |       13 | 0.554  |
|  1 | 2020-09-23   |       -1 |        |
|  1 | 2020-09-30   |       -1 |        |
```

What I am trying to do:

For each different ID (Dataframe partitioned by ID) sorted by date

Use case : row coverage column is null let's call it `rowEmptycoverage`:

1. Find in the DF the first row with `date_in_days > rowEmptycoverage.date_in_days` and with `coverage >= 0`. Let's call it `rowFirstDateGreater`
2. Then if `rowFirstDateGreater.values > 500` set `rowEmptycoverage.coverage` to 0. Set it to -1 otherwise.

I am kind of lost in mixing when join where...

Comment: Can you explain the logic more clearly? An example that illustrates all the cases would be welcome.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't clear, i tried to redescribe let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean values > 0.500 and not values > 500. Also the logic remains unclear. Here I am assuming that you are searching in the order of the column `date_in_days` and not in the order of the dataframe.

In any case we can refine the solution to match your exact need. The overall idea is to use a Window to fetch the next date for which the coverage is not null, check if `values` meet the desired criteria and update `coverage`.

It goes as follows:

```scala
val win = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date_in_days")
    .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df
  // creating a struct binding coverage and values
  .withColumn("cov_str", when('coverage isNull, lit(null))
                                    .otherwise(struct('coverage, 'values)))
  // finding the first row (starting from the current date, in order of 
  // date_in_days) for which the coverage is not null
  .withColumn("next_cov_str", first('cov_str, ignoreNulls=true) over win)
  // updating coverage. We keep the original value if not null, put 0 if values
  // meets the criteria (that you can change) and -1 otherwise.
  .withColumn("coverage", coalesce(
             'coverage,
             when($"next_cov_str.values" > 0.500, lit(0)),
             lit(-1)
  ))
  .show(false)
```

```
+---+-------------------+--------+------+-----------+------------+
|ID |date_in_days       |coverage|values|cov_str    |next_cov_str|
+---+-------------------+--------+------+-----------+------------+
|1  |2020-09-01 00:00:00|-1      |0.128 |null       |[0, 0.358]  |
|1  |2020-09-03 00:00:00|0       |0.358 |[0, 0.358] |[0, 0.358]  |
|1  |2020-09-04 00:00:00|0       |0.035 |[0, 0.035] |[0, 0.035]  |
|1  |2020-09-05 00:00:00|0       |null  |null       |[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-06 00:00:00|0       |null  |null       |[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-11 00:00:00|0       |null  |null       |[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-12 00:00:00|0       |null  |null       |[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-16 00:00:00|0       |null  |null       |[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-18 00:00:00|0       |null  |null       |[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-19 00:00:00|0       |null  |null       |[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-21 00:00:00|13      |0.554 |[13, 0.554]|[13, 0.554] |
|1  |2020-09-23 00:00:00|-1      |null  |null       |null        |
|1  |2020-09-30 00:00:00|-1      |null  |null       |null        |
+---+-------------------+--------+------+-----------+------------+
```

You may then use `drop("cov_str", "next_cov_str")` but I leave them here for clarity.

Comment: So this is what i was missing, the windows, i was turning around with join on dates, i will try this thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if that's not exactly what you wanted, I was still unsure about the exact logic ;)